# print product description on inherited delivery/receipt qweb report based on picking type in odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12, qweb

firstly, sorry for bad grammar.
can you please help me regarding inherit report.
i separated description for delivery and description for receipt in `product.product`.
i have inherited `stock.report_picking`
in which i want to print product delivery/receipt description based on it's `picking_type_id`.
it works fine.

but it prints the same description for all products in report.

here is my snippet.

```
<template id="report_picking_inherit" inherit_id="stock.report_picking">

    <xpath expr="//table[@class='table table-sm']//tbody//tr//td//span[2]" position="replace">

        <t t-foreach="o.move_ids_without_package.sorted(key=lambda m: m.product_id.id)" t-as="move">
            <t t-foreach="move.move_line_ids.sorted(key=lambda ml: ml.location_id.id)" t-as="ml">

                <t t-if="docs.picking_type_id.name == 'Receipts'">
                    <span t-field="move.product_id.description_for_receipt"/>
                </t>
                <t t-if="docs.picking_type_id.name == 'Delivery Orders'">
                    <span t-field="move.product_id.description_for_delivery"/>
                </t>

            </t>
        </t>

    </xpath>
</template>
```

and this result generated.

[E-COM12] Conference Chair (Steel) 
LEGS:STEEL, description for delivery LEGS:ALUMINIUM, description for delivery

[E-COM13] Conference Chair (Aluminium) 
LEGS:STEEL, description for delivery LEGS:ALUMINIUM, description for delivery

i have two records and it prints twice for both the products and same description.

for Conference Chair (Steel) it should print **description for Steel** and

for Conference Chair (Aluminium) it should print **description for Aluminium**

Comment: To check the type of an operation you can check picking type code.                                `t-if="o.picking_type_id.code=='outgoing'"` for delivery orders     `t-if="o.picking_type_id.code=='incoming'"` for receipts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  code

```
<xpath expr="//table[@class='table table-sm']//tbody//tr//td//span[2]" position="replace">
  <t t-if="docs.picking_type_id.name == 'Receipts'">
        <span t-field="ml.product_id.description_for_receipt"/>
  </t>
  <t t-if="docs.picking_type_id.name == 'Delivery Orders'">
        <span t-field="ml.product_id.description_for_delivery"/>
  </t>
</xpath>
```

Comment: As per checking his code he needs to show description for Receipt and delivery in Picking Operations print. so using this he can show description based on operating type.

Comment: hey, thanks buddy. i just added **t-foreach** tags which is not required.